# Hyper-V Guest (Windows 7) Running Too Fast, System Clock Racing

Tags: hyper-v

I thought I'd put this out there since I had to try quite a few things to find a solution, and this seems to be (possibly) a recent issue that cropped up in Windows 10 Fall Creators Update.

The host is Windows 10 Pro (Version 10.0.17134 Build 17134) running Hyper-V, guest is Windows 7 Pro x86 (new installation).

Symptoms:

The guest operating system acts like it is running in fast-forward.  The Windows startup animation runs 3x - 4x as fast as it would be expected to.  The cursor on the login screen blinks several times as fast as it should.  Mouse animations are several times faster than they should be.  The system clock races ahead at approximately one minute every 6-10 seconds.

Comment: 17134 is 1803 (aka Spring 2018 Update) not 1709 (aka Fall Creator's Update).

Comment: @Ramhound Understood.  I am currently running the Spring Creator's update, however there are reports from others that this issue started with the Fall Creator's update.

Comment: The "Spring Creator's Update" does not exist, if you are running 1803, then you are running **Spring 2018 Update**.  **Creator's Update** was 1703, and 1709 was **Fall Creator's Update**.  It does not really matter, but knowing what to refer to your build by, will help people answer other questions you might have.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to nested virtualization in the Windows Server 2016/Windows 10 Anniversary Update on Intel processors with VT-x and EPT.  To resolve the issue, enable virtualization extensions on the guest operating system.  From Microsoft (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization):

**Configure Nested Virtualization**

- Create a virtual machine. See the prerequisites above for the required OS and VM versions.
- While the virtual machine is in the OFF state, run the following command on the physical Hyper-V host. This enables nested virtualization for the virtual machine.

In Powershell:

`Set-VMProcessor -VMName <VMName> -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true`

- Start the virtual machine.